# Proper structure for first WP plugin?

Tags: plugin-development

This is my first WP plugin. The goal is to insert JSON-LD into the head on each page in a specific site. More advanced that simple PHP I have done up until now. It validates but may have problems other than that. Comments?

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: SEO (JSON-LD) Insert
Plugin URI:  http://www.realizetech.com/
Description: Plugin to hold SEO functions maybe more...
Version:     1.0.0
Author:      auth name
Author URI:  http://www.authname.com/
Text Domain: our-seo-insert
*/
defined('ABSPATH') or die('No direct file access allowed!');
// Modify post content
function myplugin_filter_content($content)
{
    return $content . '<p>Almost an error message but not quite.</p>';
}
add_filter('the_content', 'myplugin_filter_content');

function wpse238918_allow_schema($in)
{
    if (!empty($in['extended_valid_elements']))
        $in['extended_valid_elements'] .= ',';
    $in['extended_valid_elements'] .= '@[id|class|style|title|itemscope|itemtype|itemprop|datetime|rel],div,dl,ul,dt,dd,li,span,a|rev|charset|href|lang|tabindex|accesskey|type|name|href|target|title|class|onfocus|onblur]';
    return $in;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'wpse238918_allow_schema');

add_action('wp_head', 'wpse_43672_wp_head');
function wpse_43672_wp_head()
{
    //Close PHP tags 
?>
   <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "LocalBusiness",
    "additionalType": "http://www.productontology.org/id/Computer_repair_technician",
    "additionalType": "http://www.productontology.org/id/Computer_network",
    "additionalType": "http://www.productontology.org/id/Computer_security",
    "additionalType": "http://www.productontology.org/id/Computer_hardware",
    "priceRange" : "$500 - $20,000",
      "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "addressLocality": "Tulsa",
    "addressRegion": "OK",
    "postalCode":"74135",
    "streetAddress": "3303 S. Harvard Ave., Ste. D"
      },
      "description": "Computer repair, computer networking, computer security, computer hardware",
      "name": "Realize Information Technology, LLC",
    "email":"info@realizetech.com",
      "telephone": "918-508-2228",
    "faxNumber": "918-508-2277",
      "openingHours": "Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr 08:00-17:00",
    "image":"http://www.realizetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/LOGO-COLOR_2594x922.jpg"
    },
      "geo": {
    "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
    "latitude": "36.11",
    "longitude": "-95.94"
         },             
      "sameAs" : [ "https://www.facebook.com/Realize-Information-Technology-155305947842689/"]
    }
</script>
    <?php //Open PHP tags
}


/* Stop Adding Functions Below this Line */
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More research at the Wordpress Codex and related sites for current (2016/2017) solutions ... the following tested and works fine ...

`    defined('ABSPATH') or die('No direct file access allowed!');
// Modify post content
function myplugin_filter_content($content)
{
    return $content . '

Almost an error message but not quite.

';
}
add_filter('the_content', 'myplugin_filter_content');

function schema_TinyMCE_init($in) {
    $props = '@[id|class|style|title|itemscope|itemtype|itemprop|datetime|rel],div,dl,ul,dt,dd,li,span,a|rev|charset|href|lang|tabindex|accesskey|type|name|href|target|title|class|onfocus|onblur]';
    if (isset($in['extended_valid_elements'])) {
        if (! empty($in['extended_valid_elements'])) {
            $in['extended_valid_elements'] .= ',';
        }
        $in['extended_valid_elements'] .= $props;
    } else {
        $in['extended_valid_elements'] = $props;
    }
    return $in;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'schema_TinyMCE_init' );

add_action('wp_head', 'wpse_43672_wp_head');
function wpse_43672_wp_head()
{
    //Close PHP tags 
?>

{CORRECT JSON SYNTAX HERE}

```
<?php //Open PHP tags
```

}
/* Stop Adding Functions Below this Line */
?>
`